# Two associations for the same table resulting in a collision

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have `videos` and `artists`, video `belongsTo` artist and artist `hasMany` videos.

I did it and is working, when I find `videos` and set `[contain => ['Artists']` I got the result videos entity with the related artist.

This first relationship is about the artist that is the "owner" of the video, but I need another relationship because a video could have `N` others artists "featuring" the video.

Heres a better overview:

**Tables:**

**videos:** id (pk), artist_id (fk)

**artists_videos:** video_Id (pk), artist_id (pk)

**artists:** id (pk)

-

**Heres the code:**

```
//VideosTable
$this->BelongsTo('Artists');
$this->belongsToMany('Artists');

//ArtistsTable
$this->hasMany('Videos');
$this->belongsToMany('Videos');
```

The issue is, when I set this second relationship the first relationship stops to work, I think is happening some kind of collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call these associations with different names:

```
$this->belongsTo('Comments', [
            'className' => 'Comments',
            ...
        ]);

$this->hasMany('UnapprovedComments', [
            'className' => 'Comments',
            ...
        ]);
```

... so they're treated by the ORM as separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this since you defined "*videos*" **belongsToMany** "*artists*" [***As per your Tables***] and artists **hasMany** videos

**In the Videos Table:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Artists', [
            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id'
        ]);

$this->belongsToMany('Artists', [
            'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'artist_id',
            'joinTable' => 'artists_videos'
        ]);
```

**In the Artists Table:**

```
$this->hasMany('Videos', [
                'foreignKey' => 'artist_id'
            ]);
$this->belongsToMany('Videos', [
            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'video_id',
            'joinTable' => 'artists_videos'
        ]);
```

you can check the example at [CakePHP Examples](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html)

Then try from the [CakeDoc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together)

```
$this->hasMany('Comments', [
        'className' => 'Comments',
        'conditions' => ['approved' => true]
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('UnapprovedComments', [
        'className' => 'Comments',
        'conditions' => ['approved' => false],
        'propertyName' => 'unnaproved_comments'
    ]);
```